# how to encoding several column (but not all column) in dataframe python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I want to build a naive bayes model using two dataframes (test dataframe, train dataframe)

The dataframe contains 13 columns, but I just want to encode the dataframe from `str` to `int` value in just 5-6 columns. How can I do that with one code so that 6 columns can directly be encoded, I follow this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37159615/12977554

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

    df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colors':  ["R" ,"G", "B" ,"B" ,"G" ,"R" ,"B" ,"G" ,"G" ,"R" ,"G" ],
    'skills':  ["Java" , "C++", "SQL", "Java", "Python", "Python", "SQL","C++", "Java", "SQL", "Java"]
    })
    
    def encode_df(dataframe):
        le = LabelEncoder()
        for column in dataframe.columns:
            dataframe[column] = le.fit_transform(dataframe[column])
        return dataframe
    
    #encode the dataframe
    encode_df(df)
```

but it just only encodes 1 column, instead what I want is 6 columns with 1 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the columns and fit_transform

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']

for col in cols:
    le = LabelEncoder()
    df[col] = le.fit_transform(df[col].astype('str'))
    
df
```

Ideally you want to use same trasnfomer for both train and test dataset
For that you need to use

```py
for col in cols:
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(df_train[col].astype('str'))
    df_train[col] = le.transform(df_train[col].astype('str'))
    df_test[col] = le.transform(df_test[col].astype('str'))
        
df
```

Comment: is it automatically saved or it needs to be put ```inplace=True``` just like when u used ```fillna```?

Comment: It is automatically saved. df_train[col] = le.transform(df_train[col]) is equivalent to le.transform(df_train[col], inplace=True). You can either use the assignment operator '=' or use inplace=True. Both gives you the same result. But don't use them together.

Comment: ```TypeError: argument must be a string or number``` it produce when i build code like this

Comment: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

cols = ['Length_Employed', 'Home_Owner', 'Income_Verified', 'Purpose_Of_Loan', 'Gender']
for col in cols:
  le = LabelEncoder()
  le.fit(df[col])
  df[col] = le.transform(df[col])
  df1[col] = le.transform(df1[col])

Comment: Do you have any missing values in the dataframe? What does df[cols].info() and df[cols].isna().sum() gives you?

Comment: Length_Employed    0
Home_Owner         0
Income_Verified    0
Purpose_Of_Loan    0
Gender             0
dtype: int64

when i run ```df[cols].isna().sum()```

Comment: same with df1 too

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 21897 entries, 0 to 21896
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
 0   Length_Employed  21897 non-null  object
 1   Home_Owner       21897 non-null  object
 2   Income_Verified  21897 non-null  object
 3   Purpose_Of_Loan  21897 non-null  object
 4   Gender           21897 non-null  object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 1.0+ MB

Comment: Hi @18818181881 Please see the updated code. The data type of all the columns are converted to string before encoding

Comment: Hi, when i tried it, i also transform ```le.fit(df_train[col])``` into ```le.fit(df_train[col].astype('str'))``` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried apply(), yet ?

```
 le = LabelEncoder()
 df['colors'] = df['colors'].apply(lambda x: le.fit_transform(x))
```